# Subfigure problems

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

This is my first time using Latex. I would like to get help with sub-figure issue that I am facing.

The paper is IEEE format. I used the following code:

```
\begin{figure*}[!htbp]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig2a.jpg}
        \caption{LV}
        \label{fig:2a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig2b.jpg}
        \caption{MV}
        \label{fig:2b}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Location of DVR}
\end{figure*}
```

This gave me the following output:

[image]

As you can see, the sub-captions are not proper. It takes each sub-captions as a new figure. Also, it throws an error saying '\begin{figure*} on input line 338 ended by \end{subfigure}.

I searched in internet and added the package \usepackage{subfigure} and the output becomes:

[image]

so I added \usepackage{subcaption} and the output is weird with 229 errors: [image]

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I tried adding the \linewidth cmd to the code but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please prepare a complete small example code that allows others to reporduce the output you get.

Comment: `subfigure` is deprecated and should not be used any more. If you add `subcaption` package to your preamble, the individual `subfigure` environments need a width as in `\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}`.

Comment: Please clarify which documentclass you use. If you use `IEEEtran`, you might want to use the `subfig` package, since the class documentation recommends using `subfig` over `subcaption`.

Comment: @leandriis I am using 'conference_10179.tex' to write the paper. As I am totally new, I am not sure if this is the answer to your question. I found that subcaption package doesn't work with \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}, when I changed it to \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you use obsolete package `subfigure` Instead it try to use `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.8\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{LV}
        \label{fig:2a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.8\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{MV}
        \label{fig:2b}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Location of DVR}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Edit:**
A stated @leandriis in his coment below, IEEEtran documentation sugest to use `subfig` package, which define `\subfloat` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \subfloat[LW \label{fig:2a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}

    \subfloat[LW \label{fig:2b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\caption{Location of DVR}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Result is slightly nicer as before:

[image]

Comment: The documentation of `ieeetran` suggests using `subfig`instead of `subcaption`.

Comment: @zarko Thank you for the answer. I tried \usepackage{subcaption} earlier and it was giving me error. Now looking in to your code, I changed the 'textwidth' in my code to 'linewidth' and it is working perfectly. Thank you so much. I am not sure how it is linked but it works.